# CheckBox Listener

Tags: java, sql, checkbox

I have some CheckBoxes which are made of my database table names

```
if(event.getSource()==connect){
    CheckBox check;
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db";
        String username = "username";
        String password = "password";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        
        // Gets the metadata of the database
        DatabaseMetaData dbmd = connection.getMetaData();
        String[] types = {"TABLE"};
        
        ResultSet rs = dbmd.getTables(null, null, "%", types);
        while (rs.next()) {

            String tableCatalog = rs.getString(1);
            String tableSchema = rs.getString(2);
            String tableName = rs.getString(3);
            check = new CheckBox(tableName);
            Tables.addComponent(check);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Tables.addComponent(generate);
}
```

now lets say I get 10 checkboxes (with different names ofc.). How do I know which of them was checked?

e.g. I check box nr 1.5.7 and click on a button "Print". How do I print them out?

`System.out.println("Checked items : " +check);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`CheckboxGroup`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/CheckboxGroup.html).

```
CheckboxGroup cbg=new CheckboxGroup();
```

add a `CheckboxGroup` as follows:

```
while (rs.next()) {
   String tableCatalog = rs.getString(1);
   String tableSchema = rs.getString(2);
   String tableName = rs.getString(3);
   Tables.addComponent(new Checkbox(tableName,cbg,false););
}
```

and you get the selected value.

```
String value = cbg.getSelectedCheckbox().getLabel();
```

Comment: it would work if i would have 10 checkboxes and if i would know theyr names but i dont , the database could contain 20 tables or 3 besides those checkboxes are generated automatically(while rs.next(){"make CheckBox"})

Comment: it would probably work but because im using vaadin ill have to look for the vaadin methods , thx for the answer helped me alot

Answer (score 3):

You need a data structure like a Map to map between your checkboxes and the tables... I usually work with SWT and you have a map in each GUI component to store whatever you want, but as far as I know, you don't have this in awt, so you need to do this manually... (I assume you are using awt, although CheckBox class in awt is actually Checkbox not CheckBox!!!)
Bottom line is, you need to bind some data to your GUI components so you can recognize them later in your code...
I would use a map:

```
Map<Checkbox, String> checkToTableId;
Map<String, Checkbox> tableIdToCheck;
```

And build them up as you create the checks...